# Changing Location of an "Annotation Processor Factory" for an Android with App Engine Project

Tags: android, google-app-engine, annotations

I'm working on an Android with App Engine project based off of Github. I downloaded the project and an error that seems to be based off of the original creator's Eclipse configuration popped up.

Eclipse is looking for an "annotation processor factory" at the path where the original creator had his Eclipse folder. I have the file being looked for, but the beginning path for me is Desktop\eclipse\plugins instead of C:\Program Files\Eclipse\Eclipse-3.7.1.classic\plugins, where Eclipse is looking. Is there a way that I can change this to get it to work? I've looked and can't seem to find any information on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For both the Android project, and the AppEngine project, do the following:

Project -> Properties -> Annotation Processing -> Factory Path

Remove the JAR that is set there by default, and replace it with this one:

\plugins\com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201202290255-rel-r37\gwt-2.4.0\requestfactory-apt.jar

The version numbers will of course vary depending what version you have installed, but you want to point it to the GWT requestfactory-apt.jar

Comment: Is there any way to make it relative so that even if the skdbundle numvber changes, it can still correctly point to it?